# Can't Display [object HTMLImageElement]

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to get an image from html that I have using fetch(). I am using Cors anywhere proxy to not have a problem with CORES. Here is the code I am using that I have altered from https://gomakethings.com/getting-html-with-fetch-in-vanilla-js/. I am trying to do the same thing but cross domain. The problem is that I get [object HTMLImageElement] instead of an image. Any help is appreciated.

Thank you

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <script>
      function getimg(){
    fetch('https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://www.bing.com/images/search?q=word&form=HDRSC2&adlt=strict&first=1&cw=1366&ch=665')
    .then(function (response) {
    // The API call was successful!
    return response.text();
}).then(function (html) {

    // Convert the HTML string into a document object
    var parser = new DOMParser();
    var doc = parser.parseFromString(html, 'text/html');

    // Get the image file
    var img = doc.querySelector('img');
    console.log(img);
    //this is where I think I need to be doing something else


}).catch(function (err) {
    // There was an error
    console.warn('Something went wrong.', err);
});
      }
      getimg();
      </script>
  </head>
  <body>
<div id = myDiv>

  </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

how can I display the image instead of [object HTMLImageElement]?

Comment: This question might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6150289/how-to-convert-image-into-base64-string-using-javascript [DUPLICATE QUESTION]

Comment: @JeffVdovjak That question isn't relevant at all. This question isn't about Base64 encoding.

Comment: Have you inspected the HTML that is returned, is it what you expect?

Comment: HTMLImageElement **is** Image! It's not clear what you're trying to do. Do you want to display the image? Then just add img to your document. Do you want the URL for the image? Use `img.src`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTMLImageElement **is** Image!

```js
const img1 = new Image();
const img2 = document.querySelector('img');
console.log(img1 instanceof HTMLImageElement);
console.log(img2 instanceof HTMLImageElement);
```

```html
<img id="i">
```

It's not clear what you're trying to do. Do you want to display the image? Then just add img to your document. Do you want the URL for the image? Use `img.src`.

```js
function getimg() {
  fetch('https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://www.bing.com/images/search?q=word&form=HDRSC2&adlt=strict&first=1&cw=1366&ch=665')
    .then(function(response) {
      // The API call was successful!
      return response.text();
    }).then(function(html) {

      // Convert the HTML string into a document object
      var parser = new DOMParser();
      var doc = parser.parseFromString(html, 'text/html');

      // Get all the images file
      const images = doc.querySelectorAll('img');
      images.forEach(img => {
        // Get the image file's URL
        console.log(img.src);
        // Display the image
        img.remove();
        document.body.appendChild(img);
      });
    }).catch(function(err) {
      // There was an error
      console.warn('Something went wrong.', err);
    });
}
getimg();
```

note the first image was a 1x1 pixel image so I changed the code to show all the images. Not all of them work as you probably need to fix the URLs to be absolute instead of relative.

A few other things. `async`/`await` is so much easier IMO than `then`

```js
async function getimg() {
  try {
    const response = await fetch('https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://www.bing.com/images/search?q=word&form=HDRSC2&adlt=strict&first=1&cw=1366&ch=665');
    const html = await response.text();
    // Convert the HTML string into a document object
    const parser = new DOMParser();
    const doc = parser.parseFromString(html, 'text/html');

    // Get all the image files
    const images = doc.querySelectorAll('img');
    images.forEach(img => {
      if (!img.src) { return; }  // some images are empty.
      // make src absolute
      img.src = fixUrl('https://www.bing.com/images/search?', img.src);
      // Get the image file's URL
      log(img.src);
      // Display the image
      img.remove();
      document.body.appendChild(img);
    });
  } catch(err) {
    // There was an error
    console.warn('Something went wrong.', err);
  }
}
getimg();

function fixUrl(newPageHref, imgHref) {
  try {
    const newPageURL = new URL(newPageHref);
    const imgURL = new URL(imgHref);
    return imgURL.href.replace(imgURL.origin, newPageURL.origin); 
  } catch (e) {
    return imgHref;
  }
}

function log(...args) {
  const elem = document.createElement('pre');
  elem.textContent = [...args].join(' ');
  document.body.appendChild(elem);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, async function is much more simple.

Answer (score 0):

You probably forgot to append this image to a DOM. I changed a LINK for another because it's something wrong with the URL address and when I tried to use this link it attaches me to an image that doesn't exist and have a `display:none' which is probably a bing profile picture and I don't have an account on this site.

My local screenshot:

[image]

Example on codepen: https://codepen.io/pglejzer/pen/BaNQGwd

```js
     function getimg(){
    fetch('https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://www.sciencemag.org/news/2019/11/here-s-better-way-convert-dog-years-human-years-scientists-say')
    .then(function (response) {
    // The API call was successful!
    return response.text();
}).then(function (html) {

    // Convert the HTML string into a document object
    var parser = new DOMParser();
    var doc = parser.parseFromString(html, 'text/html');

    // Get the image file
    var img = doc.querySelector('img');
    console.log(img);
    //this is where I think I need to be doing something else

  const div = document.querySelector('#myDiv');
      console.log(div)
      div.appendChild(img)
}).catch(function (err) {
    // There was an error
    console.warn('Something went wrong.', err);
});
      }
      getimg();
```

```html
<div id = "myDiv"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`[object HTMLImageElement]` is Image Object returned by javascript.

It is not string. So you cannot add in DOM directly using `innerHTML`

Use `appendChild` to append to DOM or add to DOM using `.innerHTML` like:

```
div.innerHTML = [object HTMLImageElement].outerHTML;
```

```js
function getimg(){
fetch('https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://www.bing.com/images/search?q=word&form=HDRSC2&adlt=strict&first=1&cw=1366&ch=665')
.then(function (response) {
// The API call was successful!
return response.text();
}).then(function (html) {

// Convert the HTML string into a document object
var parser = new DOMParser();
var doc = parser.parseFromString(html, 'text/html');

// Get the image file
var img = doc.querySelector('img');
console.log(img);
//this is where I think I need to be doing something else
//document.querySelector("#myDiv"). appendChild(img);
  document.querySelector("#myDiv").innerHTML = img.outerHTML;

}).catch(function (err) {
// There was an error
console.warn('Something went wrong.', err);
});
  }
  getimg();
```

```html
  <body>
  <div id = myDiv>

  </div>
  </body>
```